# how to create an efficient frontier using R

Tags: r

I want to create an efficient frontier.

I have computed the variance and the return of my portfolios. With those data, I have created a table with 2 columns: the variance in the first one and the return in the second one.

Then, I have ranked my portfolios according to their variance (with their respective returns), from the lowest one to the highest one.

Now, I want to create an efficient frontier. This is, I don’t want to have a portfolio that would have a higher variance for the same or a lower level of return. So when starting from the first row of my table and going down to the second one, I want to be able to eliminate it if the return of the portfolio is lower than the one of the first row (with an increasing variance). I want to do this for all my portfolios.

Then, I’d like to be able to plot the result. Is it somehow possible?

Here is an illustration:

```
                   variance          return
portfolio 1         0,010              0,15
portfolio 2         0,012              0,12
portfolio 3         0,013              0,20
portfolio 4         0,014              0,21
portfolio 5         0,016              0,10 

        Rows 2 and 5 are the one that I want to eliminate.
```

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subset the dataframe to exclude rows where the return is lower than the previous return with:

```
df <- data.frame(v=c(.01, .012, .013, .014, .016), 
                   r=c(.15,.12,.20,.21,.10))
df2 <- df[c(1, which(df$r>lag(df$r))),]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using dplyr, sort by the variances, then subset to the rows that are on the rolling maximum:

```
df <- data.frame(v=c(.01, .012, .013, .014, .016), 
                 r=c(.15,.12,.20,.21,.10))
df %>% arrange(v) %>% subset(r == cummax(r))
```

EDIT:
 you can pipe that staight into ggplot:

```
df %>% arrange(v) %>% subset(r == cummax(r)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y=v,x=r)) + geom_point()
```

[image: scatterplot]

EDIT 2:

Using base R, can wrap that logic in a function:

```
frontier <- function(x, y, q=1) {      
  i <- order(x, y, decreasing = TRUE)
  i <- i[y[i] == cummax(y[i])]

  ret <- logical(length(x))
  ret[i] <- TRUE
  ret
}
```

Then `subset(df, frontier(-v,r))` works.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the best example I have come across (there are some many examples of this on the web).

```
library(stockPortfolio) # Base package for retrieving returns
library(ggplot2) # Used to graph efficient frontier
library(reshape2) # Used to melt the data
library(quadprog) #Needed for solve.QP

# Create the portfolio using ETFs, incl. hypothetical non-efficient allocation
stocks <- c(
 "VTSMX" = .0,
 "SPY" = .20,
 "EFA" = .10,
 "IWM" = .10,
 "VWO" = .30,
 "LQD" = .20,
 "HYG" = .10)

# Retrieve returns, from earliest start date possible (where all stocks have
# data) through most recent date
returns <- getReturns(names(stocks[-1]), freq="week") #Currently, drop index

#### Efficient Frontier function ####
eff.frontier <- function (returns, short="no", max.allocation=NULL,
 risk.premium.up=.5, risk.increment=.005){
 # return argument should be a m x n matrix with one column per security
 # short argument is whether short-selling is allowed; default is no (short
 # selling prohibited)max.allocation is the maximum % allowed for any one
 # security (reduces concentration) risk.premium.up is the upper limit of the
 # risk premium modeled (see for loop below) and risk.increment is the
 # increment (by) value used in the for loop

 covariance <- cov(returns)
 print(covariance)
 n <- ncol(covariance)

 # Create initial Amat and bvec assuming only equality constraint
 # (short-selling is allowed, no allocation constraints)
 Amat <- matrix (1, nrow=n)
 bvec <- 1
 meq <- 1

 # Then modify the Amat and bvec if short-selling is prohibited
 if(short=="no"){
 Amat <- cbind(1, diag(n))
 bvec <- c(bvec, rep(0, n))
 }

 # And modify Amat and bvec if a max allocation (concentration) is specified
 if(!is.null(max.allocation)){
 if(max.allocation > 1 | max.allocation <0){
 stop("max.allocation must be greater than 0 and less than 1")
 }
 if(max.allocation * n < 1){
 stop("Need to set max.allocation higher; not enough assets to add to 1")
 }
 Amat <- cbind(Amat, -diag(n))
 bvec <- c(bvec, rep(-max.allocation, n))
 }

 # Calculate the number of loops
 loops <- risk.premium.up / risk.increment + 1
 loop <- 1

 # Initialize a matrix to contain allocation and statistics
 # This is not necessary, but speeds up processing and uses less memory
 eff <- matrix(nrow=loops, ncol=n+3)
 # Now I need to give the matrix column names
 colnames(eff) <- c(colnames(returns), "Std.Dev", "Exp.Return", "sharpe")

 # Loop through the quadratic program solver
 for (i in seq(from=0, to=risk.premium.up, by=risk.increment)){
 dvec <- colMeans(returns) * i # This moves the solution along the EF
 sol <- solve.QP(covariance, dvec=dvec, Amat=Amat, bvec=bvec, meq=meq)
 eff[loop,"Std.Dev"] <- sqrt(sum(sol$solution*colSums((covariance*sol$solution))))
 eff[loop,"Exp.Return"] <- as.numeric(sol$solution %*% colMeans(returns))
 eff[loop,"sharpe"] <- eff[loop,"Exp.Return"] / eff[loop,"Std.Dev"]
 eff[loop,1:n] <- sol$solution
 loop <- loop+1
 }

 return(as.data.frame(eff))
}

# Run the eff.frontier function based on no short and 50% alloc. restrictions
eff <- eff.frontier(returns=returns$R, short="no", max.allocation=.50,
 risk.premium.up=1, risk.increment=.001)

# Find the optimal portfolio
eff.optimal.point <- eff[eff$sharpe==max(eff$sharpe),]

# graph efficient frontier
# Start with color scheme
ealred <- "#7D110C"
ealtan <- "#CDC4B6"
eallighttan <- "#F7F6F0"
ealdark <- "#423C30"

ggplot(eff, aes(x=Std.Dev, y=Exp.Return)) + geom_point(alpha=.1, color=ealdark) +
 geom_point(data=eff.optimal.point, aes(x=Std.Dev, y=Exp.Return, label=sharpe),
 color=ealred, size=5) +
 annotate(geom="text", x=eff.optimal.point$Std.Dev,
 y=eff.optimal.point$Exp.Return,
 label=paste("Risk: ",
 round(eff.optimal.point$Std.Dev*100, digits=3),"\nReturn: ",
 round(eff.optimal.point$Exp.Return*100, digits=4),"%\nSharpe: ",
 round(eff.optimal.point$sharpe*100, digits=2), "%", sep=""),
 hjust=0, vjust=1.2) +
 ggtitle("Efficient Frontier\nand Optimal Portfolio") +
 labs(x="Risk (standard deviation of portfolio)", y="Return") +
 theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill=eallighttan),
 text=element_text(color=ealdark),
 plot.title=element_text(size=24, color=ealred))
ggsave("Efficient Frontier.png")
```

http://economistatlarge.com/portfolio-theory/r-optimized-portfolio/r-code-graph-efficient-frontier